# Why can't I change the python window icon?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to change the pygame window icon with code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")
icon = pygame.image.load('snake icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

When I use that code It won't work,
like the window closed on its own,
but when I change the code to:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Snake Game")

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

It works, but It's still have the default pygame icon, i want to change the pygame icon,
can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you share the exception in the console?

Comment: There might be an issue with the icon file name having a space in it, does it work after you rename the file to `snake-icon.png` and do `pygame.image.load('snake-icon.png')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the resource (image) path and the working directory is correct.

The image file path has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python file.

The name and path of the file can be get by [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). The current working directory can be get by [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and can be changed by [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

```py
import os

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)
```

---

Furthermore see [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> [...] Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the icon before the display mode is set.

Set the icon before `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))`:

```py
icon = pygame.image.load('snake icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```