# How can I change the name of audio stream in pygame mixer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame

Currently, when I play any audio using pygame's mixer I get an audio stream called `Python (v3.8): Audio Stream` with the python logo on the side. I'd like to change the name and logo to that of my application, how can I do this?

Here is a screenshot of the audio stream:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKOGH.png

Here is an example of the code:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("forest.ogg")
mixer.music.play()

while not mixer.get_busy():
    pass
```

Comment: could you please post your code where you load and play the audio

Comment: The code is quite big, i've edited in an example with gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```py
pygame.display.set_icon(your_icon)
```

`your_icon` needs to be a `pygame.Surface` (e.g. a loaded image (`pygame.image.load(path)`)

Comment: I am not using pygame's display, just the mixer.

Comment: for me, when i ran your code, a window popped up with the default pygame icon (and the default `pygame window` caption and the music began to play. with this code the icon shown was changed. which display are you using?

Comment: I think you are getting my question wrong, I've included a screenshot of what i am trying to change. I am not using any display, just the terminal.

Comment: thank you, now i understand the question better. 1. what os are you using? 2. how did you make this GUI (and the window)?

Comment: I am on ubuntu 20.04, the screenshot if from pavucontrol (Volume Control), not my app.

Comment: I think i finally understood the problem, but this also means that i have no idea how to solve it. If i have time i will do some research about how pygame/python sends the sound to the output. and share the results

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a system generated window, but not a *Pygame* window. Some systems may not even create a window in this case. You cannot change the symbol and the label of this window with *Pygame*.

As an option you can create your own window and set the caption with [`pygame.display.set_caption()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566585/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-pygame-window/65641908#65641908) and the icon with [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809541/why-cant-i-change-the-python-window-icon) (On some systems, the icon must be set before the window is created)

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

song_name = "zelda_chest.mp3"

pygame.init()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
title_surf = font.render(song_name, True, (255, 255, 0))

pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("MusicNote.png"))
window = pygame.display.set_mode((max(400, title_surf.get_width()+20), 100))
pygame.display.set_caption(song_name)

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(song_name)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

window_center = window.get_rect().center
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run and pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(title_surf, title_surf.get_rect(center = window_center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```